# Rails 4, Acts as taggable: finding number of users with the same tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

I suspect this is straightforward. I have a user model and I am using the acts as taggable gem with this

```
  acts_as_taggable

  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
```

I want to find the number of users that have a specific tag.

I have tried

```
      User.tag_counts_on("pharmacology")
```

without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have `tag_list` attribute..which stores the tags of the users..then you can try this:-

```
tag_list=['Good','Bad','Frequent']
User.tagged_with(tag_list,:any=>true)
```

this will give you all the users with any of the tags mentioned.
View [**this**](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#user-content-finding-tagged-objects) for more info from `acts-as-taggable-on`

Comment: Worked. I added size onto it and it gave me the count for that list. Many thanks